# Prove $\ln(n) \lt n$ using only $\log(x^y) = y\log(x) $

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Prove $$\ln(n) \lt n \;\;(n\in \mathbb N) $$
Using only the rule $$\log(x^y) = y\log(x) $$
I tried using any of the known Inequalities am-gm, power mean, titu's lemma, holder's,... but I seem I can't go anywhere near required. 
Any hint?

$\mathbf {Edit} $
It was simpler than I thought, it's done with Bernoulli's Inequality. 
$$e^n\gt 2^n = (1+1)^n \ge 1+n \gt n$$
$$\ln(e^n) \gt \ln(n)$$
$$\ln(n) \lt n$$

Comment: I posted some questions earlier and showed context and my attempts but here I'm clueless.

Comment: Moreover, I didn't ask for a solution, I asked for a hint

Comment: Hints, full answer; it doesn't matter. Always provide context. Try answering the following questions (in an [edit]): What are you studying?
What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: Can't do that with *ONLY* knowing $\log x^y = y\log x$.  You have to know something about inequalities as well. .. If you know $x < y\implies e^x < e^y$ then $\ln n < n \implies e^{\ln n} = n < e^n$.

Comment: *I tried using any of the known Inequalities am-gm, power mean, titu's lemma, holder's,... but I seem I can't go anywhere near required.* This is better than no context, but you might be closer than you think, so please provide the details. Even if you're way off, it's easier for us to help you if you share what you've tried.

Comment: @fleablood I've got your hint, I don't know why I thought far more tha I should, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality could be generalized as $$\ln x \leq x-1, x>0$$ To prove it, you perhaps have to use calculus, not just elementary mathematics.Notice that, for $f(x)=\ln x-x+1,(x>0)$, $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-1.$$ Thus, $f'(x)>0,$ when $0<x<1$; $f'(x)=0$, when $x=1$; $f'(x)<0$, when $f'(x)>1.$ For the reason, $f(x)$ reaches its maximum value $f(1)=0$ at $x=0$, namely, $f(x) \leq 0$.

But if you have known **Bernoulli's inequality**, there indeed exists an elementary proof.

Since

> $$(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx,(x \geq -1, n\in \mathbb{N_+}).$$

Let $x=e-1$. Then $$e^n \geq 1+n(e-1)=1+ne-n>n.$$

It follows that $$n>\ln n.$$

Comment: Thx for the elementary proof, I stretched my thinking more than I shoud.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prove $\log(n) \lt n$ just using $\log(x^y) = y\log(x)$.

Let $k={\sqrt[3]{2}} \approx 1.259921$.

Then $\log_k(x^y) = y\log_k(x)$ as required but $\log_k(2) = 3 \not\lt 2$

Comment: You are right but I mean here the natural logarithm

Comment: Indeed, but any proof using $\log_e$ would need to use additional properties that were not true for $\log_k$. Here $\log(x^y) = y\log(x)$ is not sufficient for the proof

Comment: It's supposed to be used with some known inequality(ies)

Comment: Well, you'll have to tell us what the know inequalities are.  For example do you know that $e > 2$?  Or than $x < y \implies e^x < e^y$?

Comment: Read my post after adding my attempts

Comment: @Wolfdale Your added proof is correct but, as I suggested earlier, uses additional information about $\log_e$

Comment: @henry of course i guess the restriction means avoid calculus, thx